# Simple query regarding operators

Tags: c++, operators

Hello I'm writing a program which runs a lot of functions that run based on the user inputted menu choice which I will not be including. My question is why is the following code not responding to differences in user input. For example if I enter menu choice 1 or 4 it doesn't matter and will revert to menu choice 1. I know it has something to do with my = or == operators but neither has produced the correct result so im not sure what to do. Please help!

```
int main() //Handles the if statements concerning the menu of the program
{
int r_identifier[42]; //Variable Declaration
int year_entry[42];
 double gpa_entry[42];
 string student_name[42];
 int index = 0;
 int menuchoice; //Variable Declaration
 do
 {
    print_menu(); //Calls function to print menu
    get_selection(menuchoice); //Calls function to get the menu selection
    if (menuchoice = 1) //Calls the function to input a new user
    {
        input_new_student(student_name, r_identifier, gpa_entry, index, year_entry);
        cout << "\nThe student with R#" << r_identifier[index] << " was created. " << endl;
        index++;
    }
    else if (menuchoice = 2) //Prints all
    {
        print_all ();
    }
    else if (menuchoice = 3) //Prints statistics about all students in a particular year
    {
        int year_view;
        print_by_year(student_name, r_identifier, gpa_entry, index, year_entry);
    }
    else if (menuchoice = 4) //Prints statistics about all entered users
    {
        print_statistics();
    }
    else if (menuchoice = 5) //Quits the program
    {
        cout << "Have a good summer! ";
        cout << endl;
    }
} while (menuchoice != 5);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The = operator is for assignments. Use ==.

Comment: Why would you pass the value of (uninitialized) `menuchoice` to ``get_selection()`? You don't set the value of `menuchoice` anywhere!

Comment: @piet.t I have a function which handles menu selection input. It validates and returns the user response, 1-5.

Comment: @MordechayS When I make this change, it will simply ignore the input and re run the print_menu function over and over.

Comment: @ChrisKeenan  The line `get_selection(menuchoice);` ignores any value that might be `return`ed from the function and since `menuchoice` isn't  a pointer you won't be able to change its value from within the function.

Comment: @piet.t Ah, I see what you mean. In this case, should i make it a pointer value?

Comment: @ChrisKeenan I would prefer to use a return-value like `menuchoice = get_selection()` and add a `return choice;` to `get_selection` (if its not there). The name `get_xxx` implies it is returning a value.

Comment: @piet.t Thanks for the response! That makes sense. Would you look over my finished code thus far? It has some buggy interactions currently in the print_statistics and print_by_year that i can't explain. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/fxhPFeec

Answer (score 1):

**1**.'=' is for assignment
   Ex: int a=5 assigns 5 to the variable named a.

In ur case...u should change all ur '=' to '=='.
'==' is for comparison.
Ex: `if(a==5)cout<<a;` will print a only if a equals 5...

**2** The variable menuchoice doesnt take a value ...u should not take it as a parameter of the function getselection... Instead u can make it return the choice something like this `menuchoice=getselection()`

**3** Include an else part... it give some more meaning to the whole program instead of do while...Keep it as simple as possible :)

Comment: What a facepalm moment.. I didn't realize 2 before u said it. Thanks soo much! Would you be willing to take a look at my program as a whole and let me know why some of my functions are being weird? If so, here is the link to the code http://pastebin.com/fxhPFeec

Comment: Ya sure... @ChrisKeenan